# Proving an assertion

Tags: analysis

I need help with a proof that goes like:

Let $\left\{(a_i,b_i)\right\}_{i\in I}$ be a family of open intervals such that $\bigcup_{i\in I}(a_i,b_i)\supset[0,1]$. Prove that there exists a positive number $\epsilon$ such that for every $x\in[0, 1]$ there exists $i_x\in I$ for which $(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)\subset(a_{i_x},b_{i_x})$.

Hint: Start by assuming the opposite.

Comment: **Hint:** $[0,1]$ is compact, and $(a_i,b_i)$ is an open cover.

Comment: I am totally lost here, how does this help me?

Comment: What is the definition of compact?

Comment: Yet, I am not convinced that and only that proves a the whole deal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's fix $x \in [0,1]$. Notice that the collection of sets $\{(a_i,b_i)\}_{i \in I}$ is told to be an open cover for $[0,1]$. Since $[0,1]$ is compact, there is a finite subcover. Let $\{(a_i,b_i)\}_{i=1}^n$ be that finite subcover. Thus, $x \in (a_k,b_k)$ for some $k \in \{1,2,3,...,n\}$. Now we turn to the openness of $(a_k,b_k)$ which lets us conclude that there is some ball around $x$ of radius $\epsilon$ that is contained in $(a_k,b_k)$. Balls in $\mathbb{R}$ correspond to open intervals, so that means $(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)$ is contained in $(a_k,b_k)$ for some $\epsilon$. This completes the proof (the $(a_{i_x},b_{i_x})$ in the problem corresponds to $(a_k,b_k)$ in my solution).

Answer (score 0):

First, use compactness to reduce the problem to where $I$ is finite, so the intervals are $(a_1,b_1),\dots,(a_n,b_n)$.

For each $i$, let $e_i(x)$ be the largest value of $e$ for which $(x-e,x+e)\subset (a_i,b_i)$. Note that each $e_i(x)$ is continuous; specifically, $e_i(x)=0$ for $x\not\in (a_i,b_i)$, while the graph is a downward opening triangle for $x$ in the interval.

Now, let $e(x) = \max(e_1(x),e_2(x),\dots,e_n(x)).$ Note $e(x)>0$ for all $0\le x \le 1$, because $I$ is an open cover, and $e(x)$ is continuous. Therefore, by the extreme value theorem, $e(x)$ acheives a minimum value, $\epsilon>0$, which is the $\epsilon$ that you want.